# DNA centrifugation in water

Tags: genetics, biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, microbiology

If I have bacteria diluted in water and I centrifuge at max speed for 15-30 min, it is possible that I break the walls so the DNA can scape and I do not get any DNA pellet? or should I get it as a pellet everything togheter (lipids, proteins..) even if the mixure is just bacteria diluted in water?

Comment: At which relative centrifugation force (the "g number") do you work? And: Do you use plain water or do you add anything else? Where do these bacteria come from?

Comment: I recommend using a proper extraction kit. It may be possible (I mean anything can damage a cell wall) but you may not obtain a high yield.

Answer (score 1):

Not with bench centrifuges. 
Bacteria have cell wall and are rather small. This gives the cell wall alot of strength. I am not even sure that ultra centrifuges would work.

What you will likely get is a cell pellet. If you want DNA, pellet the cell and either go for direct PCR or sequencing. Or use a DNA extraction kit to obtain the DNA you want.

Comment: yes I use an ultra centrifuge. I am try to up-concentrate the sample but I cannot see any pellet and even when I remove volume and I resuspend the nonvisible pellet, I do real time pcr and it shows the sample was not up-concentrate, any idea why could that happen?

Comment: Why aren't you just lysing the cells first? Centrifugation isn't sufficient to lyse bacterial culture to a great degree.

Comment: Because I use bacteria direclty to do real time PCR.

Comment: *Why*? You will get more accurate qPCR results with pure DNA anyway. People only normally do colony PCR from whole cells directly as it's a quick and dirty method for checking for transformants and so on. I've never heard of anyone doing qPCR from culture, and I can't really think why you would want to?

Comment: because we use samples directly from a collector but maybe we could try to extract as you say. Thanks!